# Django filter by related fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have some Django models like this:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Order(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
```

I want get queryset with orders of particular customer.

Should I use it?:

```
Order.objects.all().filter(customer_id)
```

Or it?:

```
customer_object.orders.all()
```

And why?

Comment: Where do you want to get orders for customer?

Comment: for example, in views.

Comment: If you already have Customer object the second choice will be better

Answer (score 0):

If you have the id of the customer, you can use it like below:

```
Order.objects.all().filter(customer__id=id)
```

or if you have customer related object you can pass it directly:

```
customer = ...
Order.objects.all().filter(customer=customer)
```

This is one way to do it. It can change by how you want your application to perform.